# Perl Expect Script Exiting Prematurely

Tags: perl, expect

I have a Perl Expect script which handles file transfers. The script works fine except that it exits before the file transfer finishes. I don't want to rely on sleep() because the amount of time needed can vary.

Is there someway for expect to wait for my command to finish, before continuing?

```
my $exp = Expect->spawn("perl ./fileTransfer.pl $url")
or die "Cannot spawn program: $!\n";

#Enter credentials
$exp->send($username);
sleep(1);

$exp->send($password);
sleep(1);

#This only executes for a bit, before the program exits:
$exp->send($getFiles);
$exp->soft_close();
exit;
```

Comment: What is `$getFiles`?

Comment: $getFiles is just a string that gets sent to my main program:
$getFiles = "get externalFilePath localFilePath";

Comment: Can you use an `expect` to wait for the prompt after getting files?  `$exp->expect($timeout, ["prompt"]);`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, I wound up including this as part of my solution.

Comment: Pleasure! Glad to be of assistance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by simply using `$exp->expect(undef);`  instead of `$exp->soft_close();`
I also took @Mark Setchell 's advice and now 'expect' specific prompts, this way I can easily do multiple 'sends' without fear of one executing before the prior one finishes.